# Onsen-UI using sliding menu with navigator back button

Tags: onsen-ui

I want to turn back from a page to the home.

I'm using this example: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/qEyvxB.

But if I put a button in the browsehotels.html page to return home like this:

```
<ons-list-item ng-click="myNav.pushPage('home.html')">
     back to home
 </ons-list-item>
```

I have this error:

> Uncaught Error: NavigatorView's page stack is empty

Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `popPage()` on the page that contains the navigator, that's not possible.

If you see the code of the CodePen example that you provided, you would notice that there are a couple of errors: two navigators are declared and both have the same name, one in `browsehotels.html` and one in `home.html`.

If you want to go back to the main page, just delete the navigator in `home.html`.

Here is a working CodePen example: http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/gbNVzd

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have written another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603921/onsen-ui-back-to-home can you help me?

Comment: Yes sure!

p.s.  if the answer satisfied you, please consider accepting the answer so future searchers know that the question was answered.

Comment: hi @Andi Pavllo have you take a look at my question linked above? can you help me thanks!